# Curl command for issuing a POST request

Tags: http, curl

I am in my Terminal and I want to send a `POST` request to a given URL. I have tested this with a REST client so I know that the parameters work.

So lets say I want to POST the following parameters:

- username=tony
- password=secret

To my URL: https://exmaple.com/login/

I tried the following curl command in my Terminal (I am using OSX Lion)

```
curl --data "username=tony&password=secret" http://exmaple.com/login/
```

I get an `500 Server Error` back from the server so I am now thinking of something that could be different between the REST Client and the curl command.

Thanks for your help

**Update:** I am using a https service. Do I have to adjust my curl command to account for this?

Comment: Use the --trace-ascii option to see the data going over the wire and compare that to what the REST client sends.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. While I was doing the trace I realised that I am using HTTPS. So could it be that I need to take some precautions to account for that?

Comment: HTTPS shouldn't make a difference on a properly-installed curl. At worse, you may get a certificate validation error which you can work around (temporarily!) with the -k option.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
curl -F username=tony -F password=secret http://exmaple.com/login/
```

-F ([reference](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F)) should probably do the same as --data?  Possible the problem is in the webapp.

Maybe the app you are hitting uses basic auth for authentication?  Try this one:

```
curl --user name:password http://exmaple.com/login/
```

Comment: -F does a multipart post whereas --data does a standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so there's a good chance if one doesn't work that the other will.

Comment: i should've known that; i cut and paste that command from an article on my blog about multipart post uploads!

Comment: Okay I think there's a problem with my server that does the authentication. However I still find it curious that it works without problems with the Rest client. Do I maybe have to do some special cookies-handling?

Comment: Does the rest client defn send username/password in POST?  Maybe they use basic auth - I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: Missing cookies is a likely culprit. You may need to enable cookies in curl and then do an initial request to a home page somewhere to get a session cookie, after which this login may work.

Comment: @russau This is not the case, the authentication is done using POST parameters